# How do I properly use go modules in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, go-modules

I have used vscode 1.41.1 on my mac for a few months and it worked good until I started to use go modules for dependency management. At the moment I am rewriting a simple tool and introduce packages for separate functionalities.

My code structure looks like this:

```
├── bmr.go -> package main & main(), uses below packages
├── check
│   ├── check.go -> package check
│   └── check_test.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── push
│   ├── push.go -> package push
│   └── push_test.go
└── s3objects
    ├── s3objects.go -> package s3objects
    └── s3objects_test.go
```

My go.mod file:

```
module github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore

go 1.13

require (
        github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.28.1
        github.com/go-redis/redis v6.15.6+incompatible
        github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2
        github.com/spf13/viper v1.6.1
        github.com/stretchr/testify v1.4.0
        golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200113162924-86b910548bc1
)
```

All is fine when I invoke go test/run/build commands from the shell. But when I use 'Debug' -> 'Run Without Debugging' I get:

```
go: finding github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore/push latest
go: finding github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore latest
go: finding github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore/check latest
go: finding github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore/s3objects latest
build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore/check: module github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore@latest found (v0.0.0-20191022092726-d1a52439dad8), but does not contain package github.com/some-org/business-metrics-restore/check
Process exiting with code: 1
```

My code currently is in a feature branch and d1a52439dad8 is the first (init) and only commit on master. No code for the tool (incl. 3 mentioned non main packages) is in the master branch.
The problem here is that for some reason as you see above vscode fetches state from master and I cannot override this behaviour.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Best Regards,
Rafal.

Answer (score 23):

I realized that if the `go.mod` is not at the root of your project VSCode does not work properly. I have an AWS SAM project with the following structure:

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── nic-update
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   ├── main.go
│   ├── main_test.go
│   └── r53service
│       └── r53.go
├── samconfig.toml
└── template.yaml
```

and the only way it works if by starting VSCode from the `nic-update` directory.

My go.mod has the following content:

```
require (
    github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.13.3
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.32.12
)

module github.com/jschwindt/ddns-route53/nic-update

go 1.14
```

Comment: To further clarify what Juan just said, the root directory of a Go project is the one that has main.go file. I got this error too when I open the parent folder of the folder that contains main.go with VSCode, so VSCode got confused. In the example above, if we open nic-update using VSCode, we will not get into the error.

Answer (score 22):

> I realized that if the go.mod is not at the root of your project VSCode does not work properly

That might now (Oct. 2020) be supported, as a consequence of [gopls v0.5.1](https://github.com/golang/tools/releases/tag/gopls%2Fv0.5.1) and its experimental feature Multi-module workspace support from the [proposal 32394](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32394).

Even if you don't have multiple modules, a `go.mod` in a sub-folder (instead of the root folder of your project) will be better managed (if you activate the `gopls.experimentalWorkspaceModule` setting).

---

As noted by [kayochin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8706476/kayochin) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732657/how-do-i-properly-use-go-modules-in-vscode/64220230#comment125752868_64220230):

- The setting should be `"gopls": {"build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true}`
- See the documentation "[gopls / Settings / `experimentalWorkspaceModule bool`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/11109f614291b8974cfc7406b9a67ea686349df4/gopls/doc/settings.md#experimentalworkspacemodule-bool)".

Comment: had to restart vscode but it removed all the reds i had. Thanks

Comment: The setting should be `"gopls": {"build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true}`. For those who are interested in the docs of full settings, here is the link https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/settings.md#experimentalworkspacemodule-bool

Comment: @kayochin Thank you for this comment.  I have included yours in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

I have also had trouble with VS Code and modules. The current status of VS Code support for Go Modules is kept up to date here: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go#Set-up-your-environment

In that link they suggest ditching most of the existing extensions VS Code encourages you to install with Go and instead using the language server gopls with these directions:

> Add the below in your settings to use it.
>
> "go.useLanguageServer": true
>
> Note: You will be prompted to install the latest stable version of gopls as and when the Go tools team tag a new version as stable.

You should also fix autoimporting:

> Add the setting "go.formatTool": "goimports" and then use Go: Install/Update Tools to install/update goimports as it has recently added support for modules.

When you do these things, keep in mind that you'll also lose a couple of features:

> - Completion of unimported packages doesnt work
> - Find references and rename only work in a single package

Answer (score 0):

If the `go.mod` is not at the root of your project then starting from `go 1.18` version you can create `go.work` file which handles the problem.

Example:

```
parent
    ├── child1
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   └── main.go
    └── child2
```

If you want to run `child1` module from `parent` directory, create `go.work` in the `parent` directory:

```
go work init
```

Use `child1` module:

```
go work use child1
```

Then try to run code from `parent`.